# Understanding "Use of undeclared type" in inherited generic class

Tags: swift, generics

I just came across this curious cookie and can't figure out if I'm more surprised by the fact that this doesn't work as expected or that this the first time I'm seeing this in the past five years using Swift every day.

Now, I expected `Bar` type to be accessible from `Baz`, but it isn't:

```
class Foo<Bar> {
    func bar() -> Bar? { nil }
}
class Baz: Foo<String> {
    override func bar() -> Bar? { nil } //  Use of undeclared type 'Bar'…
}
```

It's easily solved with `typealias`:

```
class Foo<Bar> {
    typealias Bar = Bar // This just feels so wrong…
    func bar() -> Bar? { nil }
}
class Baz: Foo<String> {
    override func bar() -> Bar? { nil } //  That's it…
}
```

**My questions is:** is this mentioned or explained anywhere in the official docs? What's the benefit of hiding `Bar` from inheriting classes?

One of the reasons this is a rare case is probably because we often pass down the generic type:

```
class Foo<Bar> {
    func bar() -> Bar? { nil }
}
class Baz<Bar>: Foo<Bar> {
    override func bar() -> Bar? { nil } //  No problems…
}
```

And use protocols with `associatedtype`, which does the same job as `typealias` above:

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype Bar
}
class Foo<Bar>: P {
    func bar() -> Bar? { nil }
}
class Baz: Foo<String> {
    override func bar() -> Bar? { nil } //  All good…
}
```

P.S. **I'm not asking how to fix this.** I want to know if the current behaviour is mentioned anywhere in the official documentation or, otherwise, if there's a credible article explaining the reasons why this works the way it does.

Comment: What you are doing is called type-erasure, you erase Bar and replace it with String in the Baz class.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo<Bar>` `Bar` is just a typealias of your 'generic' type (I mean what type you want `Int`, `Double` etc.). So if you give `String` to `Foo` like (`Foo<String>`) now `Bar` alias of the `String`. And the `Bar` alias only recognizes from `Foo`.

```swift
class Foo<Bar> { 
    func bar() -> Bar? { return nil }
}
```

---

**Incorrect**

```swift
class Baz: Foo<String> {
    override func bar() -> Bar? { return nil } // `Bar` is `String` now so you should use `String?` in your return type
}
```

---

**Correct**

```swift
class Baz: Foo<String> {
    override func bar() -> String? { return nil }
}
```

---

**BONUS**

[hackingwithswift article about Swift Generics](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-generics)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm asking for any official / credible references why `Bar` isn't available in the inheriting class. There are already 3 examples how this can work with keeping the `Bar`, replacing it with a `String` is not exactly what I'm after. Please suggest an edit if this isn't clear.